# How to get random rows from table for the first time, and after return the same rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table users, where i save records of users, my problem is: i wanna return 10 random users for the first time to the first person who is asking, to the 2,3,4....person return same 10 users (result equals to the first query). How can i make it? do i need create another table when i am making request to for the first time?or is there another solution?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Postgresql. Edited.

Comment: Real randomness means randomness. It's usually achieved by calling the `RANDOM()` function - which returns different float values between 0 and 1 even if used twice in the same `SELECT`. So, no luck, it's not repeatable. Save the random sample in a new table, and work with that from then on. Alternatively, save just the primary key(s) of the randomly selected rows, and then join that key-table back to the base table to extract what you need every time.

Comment: Actually it is repeatable if you use ```setseed``` [Random](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-math.html) Table 9.6. Random Functions

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  you have interesting solution but anyway how do i get for random user the same thing? u give me fixed value  with which u  make this staff but if i have many entries more then 1000 forex, what should i do?

Comment: Unfortunately. *setseed*  likely will not work as it only repeats the sequence within the same session. If user is requesting in same session then you are ok, otherwise you need a table with a row for each user.

Comment: @Belayer. That is not what I see. It replicates across sessions.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver. Well that's good and I'll keep it in mind. However cation it's perhaps playing with fire. According to your posted reference: "If setseed() is called, the results of subsequent random() calls *in the current session* are repeatable by re-issuing setseed() with the same argument."  Admittedly, it does NOT specifically the sequence will not repeat across sessions, but neither that it will.  I would try it in dev.  with extensive testing  over  sessions over several days and users, not just a couple cases. If it avoids addition table maintenance that's great. **emphasis mine.**

Answer (score 0):

As demonstration of using `setseed` to repeat 'random' results:

```
select setseed(.5);

select line_id,t from cell_per, (select random() limit 10) as t order by random() limit 5;
 line_id |          t           
---------+----------------------
      46 | (0.2499104186659835)
       8 | (0.2499104186659835)
      10 | (0.2499104186659835)
      57 | (0.2499104186659835)
      24 | (0.2499104186659835)
(5 rows)

production(5432)=# select setseed(.5);
 setseed 
---------
 
(1 row)

production(5432)=# select line_id,t from cell_per, (select random() limit 10) as t order by random() limit 5;
 line_id |          t           
---------+----------------------
      46 | (0.2499104186659835)
       8 | (0.2499104186659835)
      10 | (0.2499104186659835)
      57 | (0.2499104186659835)
      24 | (0.2499104186659835)
```

**UPDATE**

Another example using a CTE:

```
SELECT setseed(0.5);

WITH random_lid AS (
    SELECT
        line_id,
        random()
    FROM
        cell_per
    ORDER BY
        random()
    LIMIT 5
)
SELECT
    cell_per.line_id
FROM
    cell_per
    JOIN random_lid ON cell_per.line_id = random_lid.line_id;
```

The `WITH` is the CTE(Common Table Element) that would select the same rows 'randomly' each time. You can then use these rows to join against whatever other table(s) you are using. To make it easier you could put some or all of the above in a function and call that.